# Why doesn't python support 'pass' in ternary expression?

Tags: python

I've written the following code which results in `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`:

```
self.vec.append(v1) if v1 else pass
```

I thought it would do the same thing as this code:

```
if v1:
    self.vec.append(v1)
```

Just wondering why python does not support this syntax while it supports:

```
self.vec.append(v1) if v1 else 0
```

Comment: You can do `v1 and self.vec.append(v1)`

Comment: @mypetlion I can also do self.vec.append(v1) if v1 else 0, but it does not explain why else pass is disgarded while it makes more sense.

Comment: Functions return `None` which is of `NoneType`. `pass` has no type.

Comment: Also, `pass` holds no value while `0` does

Comment: You could say `else None`

Comment: Python really only supports `self.vec.append(v1) if v1 else 0` by accident. `self.ver.append(v1)` and `0` are both expressions, so you can throw them both into an if-expression. But there's no actual reason to do so. You're not actually using their values, you're just evaluating them for side-effects, which should be done with an `if` statement. And, if you used an `if` statement, you wouldn't need an `else`, so you're actually making things _moire_ verbose, not less, here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A ternary statement is of the form:

```
<object> = <object> if <boolean expression> else <object>
```

But `pass` is not an `<object>`!

`pass` is a *keyword*, and it is used for flow control (NOOP). For instance, you can't assign `pass` to a variable:

```
>>> x = pass
Syntax Error
```

In the same way, you can't assign other keywords such as `while` to variables either:

```
>>> x = while
Syntax Error
```

---

Also, `append` returns `None`, which is certainly an `<object>`.

```
>>> print([].append(420))
None
```

Comment: That's a tricky part as Everything in Python is an object while pass is not ? Ok, if/else/while are not either.

Comment: @Pythoner Every _thing_ in Python is an object. But bits of source code that gets compiled by the compiler are not things in Python; they don't exist in the interpreter. (Well, I guess they _are_ available as strings, but the string `'pass'` _is_ an object, of type `str`, so…)

Comment: Every name in Python refers to an object. Also literals are objects. Everything else is syntax or keywords. `pass` is a keyword.

Answer (score 2):

The real issue here is that you shouldn't be writing *either* of these.<sup>1</sup>

`self.vec.append(v1) if v1 else pass` is illegal because `pass` is a statement, not an expression, and you can't put statements inside expressions.

`self.vec.append(v1) if v1 else 0` is legal, because `0` is an expression.

But just because it's *legal* doesn't mean it's code you should ever write.

The point of the `if` expression is that it's an expression, so it (a) has a value that you can use, and (b) can be used in larger expressions.

You aren't using the value of `self.vec.append(v1)` (which is `None`), or the value of `0` (which is of course `0`). You're just evaluating the first one for its side-effects and the second one as a workaround to fight against the language's syntax.

You're also not putting the expression inside another expression; you're just using it as an expression statement.

The way to write this is simple:

```
if v1:
    self.vec.append(v1)
else:
    pass
```

But of course you don't need an `else` clause here, so you can just write this as:

```
if v1:
    self.vec.append(v1)
```

Or, if you're desperate to save space:

```
if v1: self.vec.append(v1)
```

Sometimes it's worth sacrificing readability for performance, or occasionally even for brevity. But your attempt to abuse an `if` expression for its side effects is slower (especially in the false case—a jump and evaluating a literal just to discard it may be fast, but it's not nearly as fast as doing nothing at all). And it's much longer.

---

<sub>1. In fact, the worry that people would try to write code like this, even though there's absolutely no reason to, was the main argument against [PEP 308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/), the proposal to add this feature. The PEP passed only because anyone who'd be silly enough to try to write code like this is going to write Perl instead of Python anyway.</sub>

Comment: I would prefer v1 and  self.vec.append(v1) rather than if v1: self.vec.append(v1). The later is less elegant.

Comment: @Pythoner The former is less Pythonic. Not as bad as building a complicated if-expression just to ignore the value, but you're still building a simple and-expression just to ignore the value.

Comment: @Pythoner In fact, read the last paragraph of [Summary of the Current State of the Discussion in PEP 308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/#summary-of-the-current-state-of-the-discussion): reducing the abuse of `and` and `or` was actually one of the two arguments for adding ternary `if` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

One critical thing to keep straight here is that your first line of code is an **expression** and the second code snippet is a **statement**. An expression must valuate to a value while a statement is just a command that doesn't have a value.